# Sass error , File to read not found or unreadable , having trouble with scss imports

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

i am trying to import several scss to main.scss which is then executed to style.scss. but i came across a error in the main.scss that i cant understand can someone pls explain whats going wrong with the code. Thanks!
the error is as shown in the image .

[image]

Comment: Do you get the same error without those imports and some css or sass directly inputed? Technically those imports seem fine. Have you configured your outputted css file to be called `style.css`, and not `main.css`? Maybe post your node/npm config json as I don't think the scss imports are the problem? I may be wrong tho.

Comment: Thanks you ! you are right , the code are working fine, i restarted my laptop and now it seems to work fine. the funny thing is the error shows up randomly, sometimes there's no error but  here and there the error pops up. thanks again ! have a great day .